# Document contains at least one immense term - Solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr library to be indexing my documents. It is working as expected but sometimes I am getting below error. Could you please help with this?

Document contains at least one immense term in field="FileContent_en***" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped. Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms. The prefix of the first immense term is: '[110, 97, 109, 101, 61, 34, 97, 99, 113, 117, 105, 115, 105, 116, 105, 111, 110, 115, 116, 111, 114, 101, 34, 62, 101, 106, 122, 107, 118, 118]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 422071. Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large solr.StrField

Thank you in advance

Comment: try chnaging the field type of the field from string to text

Comment: Did this change worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the field type of your field to text from string.

For example your field definition should be like below.

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

> String (UTF-8 encoded string or Unicode). Strings are intended for
> small fields and are not tokenized or analyzed in any way. They have a
> hard limit of slightly less than 32K.

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Thank you so much for your response. Could you please tell us solr file name where we can do this   changes.

Comment: Solr has a folder called configset. In the same folder you will find the file named managed-schema

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Thank you so much for your response. We have verified that we have configset folder and inside that, we have only schema.xml file. we don't have managed-schema folder.

Comment: Managed-schema and schema.xml are the same.